# Using an instance of log4j to create slf4j Logger

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Typically one creates an SLF4J logger by calling `LoggerFactory.getLogger(<class>)` which doesn't allow to set the logging Level unless you create resources file is there a way to create a log4j logger instance with setting level programmatically and then use that as an instance to bind to SLF4j facade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoggerFactory in org.slf4j package could get the logger factory and let you update it.

I am using the Scala to give you example, java almost the same with Scala.

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.{Level, Logger, LoggerContext}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory


val loggerContext: LoggerContext = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory.asInstanceOf[LoggerContext]
val rootLogger: Logger = loggerContext.getLogger("root")

def setLevel(level: String) = {
  rootLogger.setLevel(Level.toLevel(level))
}
```